# PL/SQL error not a single group group-function at line 8

Tags: plsql

Hi there i currently having an error code on my pl/sql query

Here is the code:

```
declare

    people varchar2(20);
    total varchar2(20);

begin

    SELECT P.PTITLE ,COUNT(S.SNAME) into people,total
FROM POSITION P
INNER JOIN SNEEDED S
ON P.P#=S.P#
;


    dbms_output.put_line('Name :'|| people ||' '||'Total Number of Subject :'|| total);

end;
/
```

In pl/sql, can we select multiple variable and output on the same line ?

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case you can not use COUNT() keyword and another field without insert a GROUP BY clause, try this:

```
SELECT P.PTITLE ,COUNT(S.SNAME) into people,total
FROM POSITION P
INNER JOIN SNEEDED S
ON P.P#=S.P#
GROUP BY P.PTITLE;
```

Comment: Hi there, it givine me error "Exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows at line 8"

What wrong with the group now?

Comment: Oh yes if you use INTO clause you can extract only one entry, in your case the stament extracts more entries. You need to add a where-condition .. or an ugly "where rownum < 2"

Comment: How if i wanted to loop all the result out and count all the total number of ptitle in the table?

Comment: You can use FOR myEntry IN (<your-select-statement>) LOOP   dbms_output.put_line('Name :'|| myEntry.person||' '||'Total Number of Subject :'|| myEntry.total); END LOOP. In this case create alias for columns

Comment: Lets say we wanted to passed through an input parameter to the function. Is "Accept" function suitalbe for this code?